# regular expression match word or absence of word

Tags: regex, cucumber

I am trying to match the word `group` or match the absence of the word `group`

http://rubular.com/r/TKJPFvnzZ0

I can match a space but I would like it to actually match nothing. I am struggling with finding the correct syntax.

Match group 3 should contain either `group` or empty string.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you mean to match the word and at the same time to not match it?

Comment: I do not want to match AND not match. I would like to match OR not match and still capture the value.

Comment: What would you capture if there is no matched value for the given word?

Comment: If there was no matched value, it would capture nothing (empty string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but would this solve your problem:

```
^I post a "(.*?)" to the "(.*?)"(?: (group))? which the entire world can see$
```

?

Basically says that group is optional.

The `?:` inside the parenthesis marks that group as a "non-capturing group", which means that we're only enclosing that part of the expression in parenthesis to group it, but we don't want to capture the content to use after. `group` is simply enclosed in parenthesis because we want to capture that match as a group.

Comment: I've added a short explanation on the ?: syntax. You can accept the answer if it solved the problem =)